# How to integrate custom connector to Botium Box

Tags: node.js

I've created a custom connector with async-http calls (like the facebook messenger connector one) and i've a simple question about that: how to integrate with botium box?

All samples that i've found are already integrated connectors and didn't find an way to integrate with botium box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Botium is very developer friendly. If your chatbot connector exposes a HTTP/JSON api, you can most likely link it to Botium with the [Generic HTTP(S)/JSON Connector](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector)

You can also develop your own Botium connector for your chatbot, if you know Javascript:
https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/38502401/Writing+own+connector